# pydocumentdb CosmosDb Python - How to add several entries to the same document

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I try to add several entries tho the same document in Cosmo Db with Python using the library pydocumentdb

I thought that was possible with the function CreateDocuments

Creation of the Document with one entry works

```
def GetSalesOrder(document_id):
    # notice new fields have been added to the sales order
    order2 = {'id' : document_id,
            'account_number' : 'Account2',
            'purchase_order_number' : 'PO15428132599',
            'order_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,11).strftime('%c'),
            'due_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,21).strftime('%c'),
            'shipped_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,15).strftime('%c'),
            'subtotal' : 6107.0820,
            'tax_amount' : 586.1203,
            'freight' : 183.1626,
            'discount_amt' : 1982.872,
            'total_due' : 4893.3929,
            'items' : [
                {'order_qty' : 3,
                 'product_code' : 'A-123',      # notice how in item details we no longer reference a ProductId
                 'product_name' : 'Product 1',  # instead we have decided to denormalise our schema and include 
                 'currency_symbol' : '$',       # the Product details relevant to the Order on to the Order directly
                 'currecny_code' : 'USD',       # this is a typical refactor that happens in the course of an application
                 'unit_price' : 17.1,           # that would have previously required schema changes and data migrations etc.
                 'line_price' : 5.7
                }
                ],
            'ttl' : 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
            }

    return order2



coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 

print('\n1.2 Creating collection\n')

collection = client.CreateCollection(database_link,
            { 'id': "sales" })

print('\n1.2 Creating document\n')           
sales_order = DocumentManagement.GetSalesOrder("SalesOrder")
client.CreateDocument(coll_link, sales_order)
```

Then i try to reuse this code with a different entry into the same document but my program fails with :

```
Top level Error: args:('document is None.',), message:N/A
```

Thanks for your help

The complete code that fails

```
import pydocumentdb.documents as documents
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client
import pydocumentdb.errors as errors
import datetime

import config as cfg

HOST = cfg.settings['host']
MASTER_KEY = cfg.settings['master_rw_key']
DATABASE_ID = cfg.settings['database_id']
COLLECTION_ID = cfg.settings['collection_id']

database_link = 'dbs/' + DATABASE_ID
collection_link = database_link + '/colls/' + COLLECTION_ID

class IDisposable:
    """ A context manager to automatically close an object with a close method
    in a with statement. """

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.obj # bound to target

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, trace):
        # extra cleanup in here
        self = None

class DocumentManagement:

    @staticmethod
    def CreateDocuments(client): 
        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 

        print('\n1.2 Creating collection\n')

        collection = client.CreateCollection(database_link,
                    { 'id': "sales" })

        print('\n1.2 Creating document\n')           
        sales_order = DocumentManagement.GetSalesOrder("SalesOrder")
        client.CreateDocument(coll_link, sales_order)

    @staticmethod
    def AddEntry(client):
        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' #+ '/docs/SalesOrder' 
        print('\n1.2 Creating row\n')           
        sales_order = DocumentManagement.GetSalesOrder2("SalesOrder")
        client.CreateDocument(coll_link, sales_order)

    @staticmethod
    def CreateStoredProcedure(client): 
        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 
        sproc1 = {
                    'id': 'countDocuments',
                    'body': (
                        'function () {' +
                        '    var collection = getContext().getCollection(); '  +

                        '    collection.queryDocuments(' +
                        '        collection.getSelfLink(),' +
                        '        \'SELECT VALUE COUNT(SalesOrder.id) FROM SalesOrder\',' +
                        '        function(error, result) {' +
                        '            if (error) throw error;' +

                        '            var count = result[0];' +

                        '            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);' +
                        '        }' +
                        '        );' +
                        '    }'
                    )

                }
        print('\n1.2 Creating sproc\n') 
        retrieved_sproc = client.CreateStoredProcedure(coll_link, sproc1)

    @staticmethod
    def CountEntries(client):
        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 
        sproc_link = coll_link + '/sprocs/countDocuments'

        print('\n1.2 Counting rows\n')           
        #sales_order = DocumentManagement.getSalesOrder2("SalesOrder")
        #client.CreateDocument(coll_link, sales_order)   
        params = {}    

        options = {} 
        options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True

        result = client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_link, params, options)
        print(result)          


    @staticmethod
    def DeleteCollection(client):

        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 

        print('\n1.2 Delete collection\n')
        client.DeleteCollection(coll_link)

    @staticmethod
    def DeleteDocument(client, doc_id):
        coll_link = database_link + '/colls/sales' 

        print('\n1.2 Deleting Document by Id\n')
        doc_link = coll_link + '/docs/' + doc_id

        client.DeleteDocument(doc_link)


    @staticmethod
    def GetSalesOrder(document_id):
        # notice new fields have been added to the sales order
        order2 = {'id' : document_id,
                'account_number' : 'Account2',
                'purchase_order_number' : 'PO15428132599',
                'order_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,11).strftime('%c'),
                'due_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,21).strftime('%c'),
                'shipped_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,15).strftime('%c'),
                'subtotal' : 6107.0820,
                'tax_amount' : 586.1203,
                'freight' : 183.1626,
                'discount_amt' : 1982.872,
                'total_due' : 4893.3929,
                'items' : [
                    {'order_qty' : 3,
                     'product_code' : 'A-123',      # notice how in item details we no longer reference a ProductId
                     'product_name' : 'Product 1',  # instead we have decided to denormalise our schema and include 
                     'currency_symbol' : '$',       # the Product details relevant to the Order on to the Order directly
                     'currecny_code' : 'USD',       # this is a typical refactor that happens in the course of an application
                     'unit_price' : 17.1,           # that would have previously required schema changes and data migrations etc.
                     'line_price' : 5.7
                    }
                    ],
                'ttl' : 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
                }

        return order2

    @staticmethod
    def GetSalesOrder2(document_id):
        order = {'id' : document_id, 'account_number' : 'Account3',#
                                'purchase_order_number' : 'PO15428132601',
                                'order_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,11).strftime('%c'),
                                'due_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,21).strftime('%c'),
                                'shipped_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,15).strftime('%c'),
                                'subtotal' : 6107.0820,
                                'tax_amount' : 586.1203,
                                'freight' : 183.1626,
                                'discount_amt' : 1982.872,
                                'total_due' : 4893.3929,
                                'items' : [
                                    {'order_qty' : 3,
                                     'product_code' : 'A-123',      # notice how in item details we no longer reference a ProductId
                                     'product_name' : 'Product 1',  # instead we have decided to denormalise our schema and include 
                                     'currency_symbol' : '$',       # the Product details relevant to the Order on to the Order directly
                                     'currecny_code' : 'USD',       # this is a typical refactor that happens in the course of an application
                                     'unit_price' : 17.1,           # that would have previously required schema changes and data migrations etc.
                                     'line_price' : 5.7
                                    }
                                    ],
                                'ttl' : 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
                                }

def run_sample():
    with IDisposable(document_client.DocumentClient(HOST, {'masterKey': MASTER_KEY} )) as client:
        try:
            DocumentManagement.CreateDocuments(client)
            DocumentManagement.CreateStoredProcedure(client)
            DocumentManagement.CountEntries(client)
            DocumentManagement.AddEntry(client)
            DocumentManagement.CountEntries(client)

            DocumentManagement.DeleteDocument(client,'SalesOrder')
            DocumentManagement.DeleteCollection(client)


        except errors.HTTPFailure as e:
            print('\nrun_sample has caught an error. {0}'.format(e.message))

        finally:
            print("\nrun_sample done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run_sample()

    except Exception as e:
            print("Top level Error: args:{0}, message:N/A".format(e.args))
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by “different entry in the same document “? Are you trying to update the same document. Please edit your question and include these details. Also include the actual code that is failing.

Comment: I would like to be able to create a document with several rows like this [{"id" : "SalesOrder", "prop1" : "value1"}, {"id" : "SalesOrder""prop2":"value2"}] , one time with CreateDocument or step by step

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. If I am not mistaken, your code is failing at this line: `DocumentManagement.AddEntry(client)`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes , and even if i change the doc_id name (should be a new document)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because your `GetSalesOrder2` method is not returning anything (or in other words returning an `undefined` object). If you look closely it is missing `return` statement. Please change this method to something like:

```
  def GetSalesOrder2(document_id):
      order = {'id' : document_id, 'account_number' : 'Account3',#
                              'purchase_order_number' : 'PO15428132601',
                              'order_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,11).strftime('%c'),
                              'due_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,21).strftime('%c'),
                              'shipped_date' : datetime.date(2005,7,15).strftime('%c'),
                              'subtotal' : 6107.0820,
                              'tax_amount' : 586.1203,
                              'freight' : 183.1626,
                              'discount_amt' : 1982.872,
                              'total_due' : 4893.3929,
                              'items' : [
                                  {'order_qty' : 3,
                                   'product_code' : 'A-123',      # notice how in item details we no longer reference a ProductId
                                   'product_name' : 'Product 1',  # instead we have decided to denormalise our schema and include 
                                   'currency_symbol' : '$',       # the Product details relevant to the Order on to the Order directly
                                   'currecny_code' : 'USD',       # this is a typical refactor that happens in the course of an application
                                   'unit_price' : 17.1,           # that would have previously required schema changes and data migrations etc.
                                   'line_price' : 5.7
                                  }
                                  ],
                              'ttl' : 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
                              }

      return order
```

Also, each document in a collection need to have a unique id so please define a different id for this document.

Comment: Thanks so mutch , ok i understand , one row is one document in the collection. one unique doc id. What a shitty mistake sorry

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that your problem is solved. And yes, your understanding is correct - one row is one document in the collection and each document should have a unique id.